# How to extract data from an already filled up pdf form using any program language?

Tags: java, php, c, forms, pdf

I have a pdf form, I've filled the fields in that form and saved that pdf file as a new pdf file. Now when I open the new pdf file, it automatically loads the data which was filled in earlier. Can I extract that data using any of the language from C/Java/PHP/Javascript, so that I can use that and save that into database?

Comment: Yes you can. Read the PDF specification, then write a program to read the PDF file and extract the user data from it. You may use C, Java or PHP for that. I am not sure it is possible with Javascript. Good luck!

Comment: But which answer will you accept? The one with the PHP solution? The C one? The Java one?

Comment: The order is  C then PHP then JAVA, but it doesn't matters actually, any language from the set above

Comment: Requests for [just code](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help5) are usually off-topic. Primary site intent is coding approaches, not readymade solutions, nor [tutoring](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help6) per se.

Comment: @hakre Hey I was not asking for a direct code, Iwas asking for any api/llibraries available

Comment: @user1706482: That is merely the same, please focus on concrete programming questions, you need to do most of the research your own I'd say, you could then - as it was work for you - create a question out of it and answer it your own. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/#

Comment: Also try to find out how that specific feature your looking for is using specific parts of the PDF standard, name those parts. Next to your own wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Easiest solution may be to use a PDF library to access the file.

PHP: http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/